# How to enter docker containers deployed on Google cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have deployed my application via docker on Google Kubernetes cluster. I am facing an application error due to which I want to enter inside the container and check a few things. At local, all I had to do was run `sudo docker ps` and then exec -it into the container.

How can I do that when containers are deployed on a Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: check if there are any pods running in other namespaces or not `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use kubectl

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl exec -it pod-container-name -- /bin/bash
```

Comment: I am getting `no resources found` even though I got the deployment done successfully.

Comment: Did you deploy using kubectl?

Comment: I used -n [my namespace] to get the pods listed,

Comment: And your 2nd command is not working. I am getting the error: `Error from server (NotFound): pods "pallet-airflow-scheduler-6ddbb49586-wnr8q" not found` after running the command: `kubectl exec -it pallet-airflow-scheduler-6ddbb49586-wnr8q -- /bin/bash -n pallet`

Comment: Does container is failing and keeps restarting?

Comment: It is `1/1 Running`

Comment: Try add --namespace="my namespace]" parameter

kubectl exec -it pallet-airflow-scheduler-6ddbb49586-wnr8q --namespace="my namespace" -- /bin/bash -n pallet

Comment: can run command `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and share the output? @Edmhs

Comment: yes, i am able to get into pods and do my debugging. Thanks.
the catch was to put namespace tag before the pod name

Comment: @aviralsanjay, please note, that above command will allow you get into first container inside your POD. If your POD is running more than one container you need to also specify an extra argument: -c='<Container name>'